# Making a string safe by removing all javascript codes and events

Tags: php

I want to remove all javascript codes from a string that contains html code.

For example these are some unwanted javascript codes that may cause problems on your website:

```
<div onmouseover='window.location = "http://To-Undesirable-Location"'></div>
```

or

```
<img onload='window.location = "http://To-Undesirable-Location"'></img>
```

or

```
<script language="javascript> ...unwanted code... </script>
```

*Since hackers can use this js functions to redirect your page to some unwanted pages I wonder why there are not some good source to make this type of content safe... On any website there are usually a simple WYSIWYG editor that users can put their html content inside it.*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard good things on Stack Overflow about [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).